# Position argument of geom_text to set different tags

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want three tags in each of my stacked bars. One I want it to be at the top of each bar saying the total number of observations per treatment variable (x axis). The other two tags I want them showing the number of observations per gender, to be somehwere in the middle of each Gender option within each treatment variable.

I have problems with the geom_text code, since I don't know what position I should try. I have input different options, but when I do, my graph is distorted like this.

[image]

This is the code I am using

```
Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment, Gender) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, n))+ 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Gender), position = "fill")+
  ggtitle("Gender")+
  ylab("Fraction")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.3, hjust=1))+
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", 
                    values = c("Female" = "pink", "Male" = "light blue",
                               "Other"="coral", "Prefer not to answer"="violet"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=n), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

If I have read correctly other posts, position_stack should put the numbers inside each bar.

Comment: In `geom_text` use `position_fill`.

Answer (score 1):

If the cols are plotted with `position = "fill"` then `geom_text` must call the same `position_fill`.
In this example I will use a subset of the built-in dataset `mtcars`, transformed below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment, Gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = n, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  ggtitle("Gender") +
  ylab("Fraction") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.3, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", 
                    values = c("Female" = "pink", "Male" = "light blue",
                               "Other"="coral", "Prefer not to answer"="violet")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

To put the bars totals on top of them, the following code also computes the totals per `Treatment` and keeps only the first per group of `Treatment`, assigning `NA` to the other elements of `SumN`.

```
Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment, Gender) %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  mutate(SumN = sum(n),
         SumN = c(SumN[1], rep(NA, length(SumN) - 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = n, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  ggtitle("Gender") +
  ylab("Fraction") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.3, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", 
                    values = c("Female" = "pink", "Male" = "light blue",
                               "Other"="coral", "Prefer not to answer"="violet")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1.1, label = SumN), position = position_fill(vjust = 1.2))
```

[image]

**Data example.**

```
Data1 <- mtcars[mtcars$carb %in% 1:4, c("cyl", "carb")]
names(Data1) <- c("Treatment", "Gender")
Data1$Treatment <- factor(Data1$Treatment)
Data1$Gender <- factor(Data1$Gender, 
                       labels = c("Female", "Male", "Other", "Prefer not to answer"))
```

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to set a label of the number of observations at the top of each bar

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz Done, see the edit. I have also changed the data creation code by adding a `Treatment <- factor(Treatment)` code line.

Comment: I ran the code, but this appears: 
Warning message:
Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_text).

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz That is normal, as long as the graph is right, I wouldn't worry if I were you.