# I'd like to show data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have successfully created a stacked bar plot but I cannot add labels indicating the percentages. That is all that I am missing. 
I basically do not know how to use the geom_label/geom_text correctly, I have tried many many solutions but nothing has worked for me.

[image]

I have tried the geom_text function but it keeps telling me I am doing it wrong.

```r
year Month2 Month Day HE Supply MUnit    MPrice MBlock Fuel
2017    1   Jan   01    8   9408    SD2  15.38  126   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    9   9388    SD3  15.46  218   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    10  9393    SD3  15.46  218   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    11  9628    SD4  15.47  203   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    12  9943    EGC1 21.40  72    GAS
2017    1   Jan   01    13  10106   BR5  21.41  245   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    14  10114   BR5  21.41  245   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    15  9971    EGC1 20.75  75    GAS
2017    1   Jan   01    16  10302   BR5  21.41  245   COAL
2017    1   Jan   01    17  10655   TC01 22.77  11    GAS
2017    1   Jan   01    18  10811   CAL1 24.88  25    GAS
2017    1   Jan   01    19  10821   CAL1 24.88  25    GAS
2017    1   Jan   01    20  10765   BIG  26.00  30    HYDRO
2017    1   Jan   02    8   10428   CAL1 22.04  30    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    9   10723   CAL1 29.97  59    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    10  10933   BRA  44.50  30    HYDRO
2017    1   Jan   02    11  11107   ANC1 46.46  63    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    12  11098   ANC1 46.46  38    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    13  10839   JOF1 26.59  45    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    14  10814   JOF1 26.09  15    GAS
2017    1   Jan   02    15  10797   BIG  26.00  30    HYDRO

sp <- ggplot(data = MU17) +      
       geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = factor(Month,levels=month.abb),
                fill = factor(Fuel, levels=c("COAL", "GAS","HYDRO","BIOMASS"))),
                position = "Fill") +
       scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) 


sp + scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("COAL", "GAS","HYDRO","BIOMASS"), 
                      values=c("black","yellow","blue","green")) + 
     labs(x = "2017" , y="Marginal Fuel Between HE8 & HE20") + 
     labs(fill="Fuel Type")
```

I am hoping to get the exact same plot that I get, just with labels indicating percentages.

Comment: you need to share some of your data. read here to learn how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you try the answers at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)?  If one of those didn't work, add the code you tried along with your example data so folks can see where things might have gone wrong.

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485047/position-argument-of-geom-text-to-set-different-tags/56485465#56485465)? Your question seems a lot like a duplicate.

Comment: @aosmith, Yes, I have tried those. Basically every solution I have tried gives me the same message: Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y. 
I'm just trying to teach myself R, for the most part I have been able to figure things out alone, though I have been stuck with this for almost 2 weeks now.

Comment: It's helpful to show an attempt so we can address what you're actually doing wrong rather than just show you a working solution. From the error message you mention in comments, I think the problem is that you're specifying `aes()` in the `geom_bar()` layer, so it is local to that layer and not inherited by the geom text layer. If you put your `aes()` argument inside `ggplot()` instead of inside `geom_bar()`, you should be able to get the other solutions to work.

Comment: The error comes from the place where you define the aesthetics. It's a frequent error **not to define them in the initial call to `ggplot`**. Try moving `aes(x = etc)` from `geom_bar` to `ggplot()`.

Comment: Also, I would use `geom_label` to have a background of a different color, since the bars colors are so dark.

Comment: One of the real complications here is that you are trying to have ggplot2 calculate the labels for you (as it calculated the bars for you).  I think the most straightforward thing to do is to calculate the percentage of `Fuel` for each `Month` outside of **ggplot2** and then make the plot using that `y` value.  If you do this you can use an approach much more similar to the linked answers.

Comment: Right on. Thank you guys , I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using `geom_col` over `geom_bar` and process the data myself rather than let ggplot2 do it. This way you have more control over whats going on.

Since you have not provided all of you data I just use the snippet you provided.

```
library(tibble)
MU17 <- tribble(~year, ~Month2, ~Month, ~Day, ~HE, ~Supply, ~MUnit, ~MPrice, ~MBlock, ~Fuel,
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    8,   9408,    "SD2",  15.38,  126,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    9,   9388,    "SD3",  15.46,  218,  "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    10,  9393,    "SD3",  15.46,  218,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    11,  9628,    "SD4",  15.47,  203,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    12,  9943,    "EGC1", 21.40,  72,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    13,  10106,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    14,  10114,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    15,  9971,    "EGC1", 20.75,  75,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    16,  10302,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    17,  10655,   "TC01", 22.77,  11,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    18,  10811,   "CAL1", 24.88,  25,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    19,  10821,   "CAL1", 24.88,  25,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   01,    20,  10765,   "BIG",  26.00,  30,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    8,   10428,   "CAL1", 22.04,  30,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    9,   10723,   "CAL1", 29.97,  59,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    10,  10933,   "BRA",  44.50,  30,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    11,  11107,   "ANC1", 46.46,  63,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    12,  11098,   "ANC1", 46.46,  38,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    13,  10839,   "JOF1", 26.59,  45,    "GAS",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    14,  10814,   "JOF1", 26.09,  15,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    1,   "Jan",   02,    15,  10797,   "BIG",  26.00,  30,    "BIOMASS",

                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    8,   9408,    "SD2",  15.38,  126,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    9,   9388,    "SD3",  15.46,  218,  "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    10,  9393,    "SD3",  15.46,  218,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    11,  9628,    "SD4",  15.47,  203,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    12,  9943,    "EGC1", 21.40,  72,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    13,  10106,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    14,  10114,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    15,  9971,    "EGC1", 20.75,  75,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    16,  10302,   "BR5",  21.41,  245,   "COAL",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    17,  10655,   "TC01", 22.77,  11,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    18,  10811,   "CAL1", 24.88,  25,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    19,  10821,   "CAL1", 24.88,  25,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   01,    20,  10765,   "BIG",  26.00,  30,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    8,   10428,   "CAL1", 22.04,  30,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    9,   10723,   "CAL1", 29.97,  59,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    10,  10933,   "BRA",  44.50,  30,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    11,  11107,   "ANC1", 46.46,  63,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    12,  11098,   "ANC1", 46.46,  38,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    13,  10839,   "JOF1", 26.59,  45,    "GAS",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    14,  10814,   "JOF1", 26.09,  15,    "HYDRO",
                    2017,    2,   "Feb",   02,    15,  10797,   "BIG",  26.00,  30,    "BIOMASS"
    )
```

When doing the processing I calculate:

```
the number of occurences/observations  (n)
their relative frequency per month (p)
a percent label of p (p2)
the y-position in the bar chart of each label (pos)
```

This data I pipe into ggplot. Important is that I use `geom_col` with `position = “fill”`. Since I provide a positon value `pos` for `geom_text`, it is necessary to use `position = “identity”` here . Further, you need some kind of `ifelse`-Statement to adjust the `colour` of `geom_text` to white `#FFFFFF` for darker background colors in `HYDRO` and `COAL`.

Good luck using this approach on your original data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

MU17 %>%
    mutate(Fuel = factor(Fuel), 
           Month = factor(Month,levels = month.abb)) %>% 
    group_by(Month, Month2, Fuel) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    mutate(p = n / sum(n),
           p2 = paste(formatC(p*100, digits = 2, format = "fg"),"%",sep = ""),
           pos = cumsum(p) - (0.5 * p)) %>%

    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = p, fill = factor(Fuel, levels = rev(levels(Fuel))))) +   
    geom_col(width = 0.5, position = "fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = c(-.5,-.25,0,.25,.5,.75,1), expand = c(0, 0), 
                       labels = scales::percent) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("COAL", "GAS","HYDRO","BIOMASS"),
                      values = c("black","yellow","blue","green")) +
    geom_text(aes(label = p2, y = pos),
              position = "identity",
              vjust = 0.5,
              colour = ifelse(data$Fuel == "COAL" | data$Fuel == "HYDRO", "#FFFFFF", "#000000")) + 
    labs(x = "2017" , y = "Marginal Fuel Between HE8 & HE20") +
    labs(fill = "Fuel Type")
```